# I need to make a variadic function with user input in C

Tags: c, function, input, struct, variadic

I need to sum an array `int kviz[10]` from a structure. The array has 10 elements which are integers and the structure is an array it self `[120]`. I need to let user pick how many elements he wants to sum (ex: first, secont and fifth integer from `int kviz[10]`) and the sum needs to be done for the whole strucnt [120]. It needs to be done with a variadic function. The function needs to return the sum of the array for the whole structure because i need to sort structures later on based on result.

structure:

```
typedef struct studenti
{
    char index[10];
    char ime[20];
    char prezime[20];
    int kviz[10];
} studenti[120];
```

my attempt:

```
int sumaK(studenti student,*redniBrojKviza, int *brojKviza,...)
{
    int suma;

    va_list argumenti;

    argumenti = redniBrojKviza;

    for(int i=0;  ;i++)
    {
    argumenti = student.kviz[i];
    }

    va_start (argumenti, brojKviza);

    for(int x = 0; x < brojKviza; x++ )
    {
        suma += va_arg (argumenti, brojKviza);
    }

    va_end (argumenti);

return suma;
}
```

main function - this is where I need to let user input values:

```
printf("Unesite broj kvizova: %d", brojKvizova);
scanf("%d", &brojKvizova);

for(int s=0;s<brojKvizova;s++)
{

    printf("Unesite redni broj kviza: ");
    scanf("%d", &redniBrojKviza);

}

sumaK(brojKvizova,redniBrojKviza);
```

Comment: You can't. You need to use an array.

Comment: Why ius `brojKviza` declared as a pointer? And if it's a pointer, you need to dereference it: `x < *brojKviza`.

Comment: The call to the function needs to have at least 3 arguments. The variadic arguments come after those.

Answer (score 0):

Variadic functions provide for *different calls* to the same function specifying different numbers of arguments and / or arguments of different types:

```
// The same foo() in all cases:
foo(1, 2, 3);
foo(1, 2);
foo(42, "!");
```

That's not what you're trying to do.

You seem to want the *same* function call expression to be handled as if it specified different numbers of arguments under different circumstances, but C has no provision for that.  You can always count the number of arguments in a function call expression by looking at the call expression alone -- the argument count does not vary with the values of the arguments.

Therefore, varargs is not suited to your use case.  There is a variety of alternatives you could use for the problem described, all of which involve passing all of the user's runtime column selections via a fixed number of arguments.  For example, given that there are only ten columns to choose among, you might encode the selections as a single `int`.  Or you might put them in an array, and pass that plus an element count.  In principle, you might even declare a separate `_Bool` parameter for each column, but that would be very hard to use for your purposes.